# 'ascii' codec can't decode - CSV to SQL Server via pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, csv, pyodbc, non-ascii-characters

I have searched for numerous examples but none have been able to solve my specific issue. Thanks for taking the time as I cannot for the life of me find a way around this. I am attempting to insert a CSV file into a Azure SQL Server Database using a for loop in Python. I have used this same python program numerous times will multiple different CSV files so I know the underlying issue is with this current CSV. Below is a brief snippet of my Python code, along with the error. How can I encode the CSV so this error no longer occurred (as mentioned, I have tried solutions from multiple similar threads and have not be able to solve this).

Code:

```
   csvfile = open('C:\\file.csv', 'r')
   csv_data = csv.reader(csvfile)

   SQL = """Insert into Idea_Pipeline( [col_1], [col_2], [col_3], [col_4])
            values (?,?,?,?)

   for row in csv_data:
   first_row = next(csv_data)
   cursor2.execute(SQL, row)
```

As mentioned, this is just a snippet of my code, however I have used this numerous times so I know the syntax is correct. Below is the error that I cannot resolve.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Idea_Pipeline.py", line 46, in <module>
cursor2.execute(SQL, row)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 114: 
ordinal not in range(128)
```

Again, thank you so much for all the help.

Also - I have tried Bulk Inserting this CSV into a local SQL Server Database and have been receiving the error "Operating System Error Code (null)"

Thanks again for any help or advice as I am still somewhat new and am trying to learn as much as I possible can.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like this is the first time that your CSV file has contained characters that the 'ascii' codec cannot process. `0x96` is not one of the characters in the `latin1` character set, so the next most likely candidate is probably `windows-1252` in which `0x96` represents the "En Dash" character (U+2013). If that is the case then

```python
# -*- coding: windows-1252 -*-
import csv
import pyodbc
import sys
print("Python version " + sys.version)
print("pyodbc version " + pyodbc.version)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=myDb", autocommit=True)
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
crsr.execute("CREATE TABLE #foo (id INT PRIMARY KEY, txtcol VARCHAR(50))")

with open(r'C:\Users\gord\Desktop\sample.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    csv_data = csv.reader(csvfile)
    sql = "Insert into #foo ([id], [txtcol]) VALUES (?,?)"
    print("")
    print("Rows retrieved from CSV file:")
    for row in csv_data:
        print(row)
        crsr.execute(sql, [cell.decode('windows-1252') for cell in row])
print("")
print("Values retrieved from table:")
for row in crsr.execute("SELECT * FROM #foo").fetchall():
    print(row)
cnxn.close()
```

will produce the following output

```
Python version 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
pyodbc version 4.0.16

Rows retrieved from CSV file:
['1', 'foo']
['2', 'test\x96data']

Values retrieved from table:
(1, u'foo')
(2, u'test\u2013data')
```